# Making volley request with return value

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am new to Android Volley requests. I have managed to make post and get requests to the server and get the response.

```
 public void getCardDetails() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException { 
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response from server","Customer Account"+response);

                    try {
                        results = signInActivity.splitQuery(response);

                        String encodedMessage = results.get("encodedMessage");
                        String serverSignature = results.get("signature");
                        //Log.d("CustomerAccount","encodedMessage:"+ encodedMessage);


                        String decodeMessage = security.decodeBase64(encodedMessage);
                        Log.d("CustomerAccount","DecodedMessage"+ decodeMessage);
                        customerDetailsXML = decodeMessage;



                        try {
                            String computedSignature = security.hashMac(decodeMessage, signature_key);



                                int responseCode = xmlHandler.getResponseCode(decodeMessage);
                                Log.d("CustomerAccount","Response Code: "+responseCode);

                            if (responseCode == 1001){
                                getCardBalance();


                                Log.d("CustomerAccount","Success");
                            }
                        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JDOMException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }

    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=\"utf-8\"");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            headers.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            headers.put("Pragma", "no-cache");
            headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            headers.put("Content-length", dataStream.toString());
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("encodedMessage", encodedMessage_req);
            params.put("signature", signature);

            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);

}
```

The above request get the server response in a String XML format. I want to be able for the method in which i do the request to return the XML so i can manipulate it as i want out of the request method.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Create interface class and get the response then implement wherever  you execute api

Comment: You already have `customerDetailsXML`, so where's the issue?

Comment: The customerDetailsXML is null outside the volley request method. If there is a way to correct that then its fine.

Comment: You should not be using the variables before the Volley request finishes. It's only null because it's not assigned yet.

Comment: where should i use the variable customerDetailsXML in order for me to be able to use it outside the volley request method?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

1. make an interface class:

   `public interface MyListener{
      public void myMethod(String response);
   }`
2. change your method inputs:  `public void getCardDetails(MyListener listener)`
3. in your  `public void onResponse(String response)`

add this:

```
`listener.myMethod(response);`
```

Comment: Volley has its own listener class. Don't need your own interface

Comment: @cricket_007 if you want exit from volley listener and do next action in other place, you must use your own listener. :)
why you do all thing in volley listener? it is not suitable. because your network stay busy.

Comment: Sure, but you lose the error listener along the way with your current  implementation

Comment: @cricket_007 because our friend that ask question, focus on Response Listener, not Error Listener.  so I just show Response Listener... you can add it in case you need it.

Comment: after i use what you have provided me how do i use the interface in order to get the response outside of the volley request?

Comment: @pavlos
anywhere you call this method getCardDetails(MyListener listener) do like below:
`getCardDetails(new MyListener(){
      public void myMethod(String response){
          // do whatever you want!
}
});`